# Neither is or are

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, disjunction, neither-nor

Should this be *neither is* or *neither are*?

> Neither of these two books is suitable.
>
> Neither of these two books are suitable.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?

Answer (score -6):

Because BOTH are unsuitable, THEY ARE unsuitable. Thus, "are" must be used.

Comment: The question is with respect to using the word "suitable".

Comment: Then shall you refute my answer?

Comment: I did. Your premise is wrong. I'm guessing you were down voted for the reason I gave.

Comment: My downvote is because a far more acceptable (and conflicting) answer was given the last time round, as flagged by tchrist, and this seems not to have been even considered. At [languagetips](http://languagetips.wordpress.com/category/neither-singular-or-plural/) is the marvellous 'Neither of the boys was eligible for the prize. TRADITIONALLY CORRECT //

Neither of the boys were eligible for the prize. NON-TRADITIONALLY CORRECT'